# How to produce an HTTP 403-equivalent WCF Message from an IErrorHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, error-handling

I want to write an [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) implementation that will handle `AuthenticationException` instances (a proprietary type), and then in the implementation of `ProvideFault` provide a traditional Http Response with a status code of 403 as the fault message.

So far I have my first best guess wired into a service, but WCF appears to be ignoring the output message completely, even though the error handler is being called.

At the moment, the code looks like this:

```
public class AuthWeb403ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
  #region IErrorHandler Members
  public bool HandleError(Exception error)
  {
    return error is AuthenticationException;
  }

  public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
  {
    //first attempt - just a stab in the dark, really
    HttpResponseMessageProperty property = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
    property.SuppressEntityBody = true;
    property.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    property.StatusDescription = "Forbidden";

    var m = Message.CreateMessage(version, null);

    m.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = property;
    fault = m;
  }
  #endregion
}
```

With this in place, I just get the standard WCF html 'The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.' - which is what would happen if there was no IErrorHandler.  Is this a feature of the behaviours added by WebServiceHost?  Or is it because the message I'm building is simply wrong!?  I can verify that the event log is indeed not receiving anything.

My current test environment is a WebGet method (both XML and Json) hosted in a service that is created with the WebServiceHostFactory, and Asp.Net compatibility switched off.  The service method simply throws the exception in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
[Returning Error Details from AJAX-Enabled WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272877/returning-error-details-from-ajax-enabled-wcf-service)

and this

http://zamd.net/2008/07/08/error-handling-with-webhttpbinding-for-ajaxjson/

Comment: @Christo - thanks for searching and finding these.  I ended up implementing an IErrorHandler to produce the correct http responses (just forgot to post my solution here!); the way I did it being nigh on the same as these.

Comment: no worries - I came across them whilst searching for a solution to the same problem. And also came across your question, so thought I'd post them as an answer to your Q