# IErrorhandler not returning to Client

Tags: c#, wcf, ierrorhandler

I'm trying to implement the `IErrorhandler` which is proving to be a real pain!

I have imlpement the provideFault method from the `IErrorhandler` interface like so...

```
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        FaultException<ServiceFault> faultException = ServiceMethods.BuildFaultException<ServiceFault>("Provide Fault Error", error.Message);
        MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();

        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);
    }
```

If my service operations hit an exception it drops into this method to create a `FaultException`. My problem is the client doesnt get this `FaultException` returned to them.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are not seeing a `FaultException<ServiceFault>` client-side, double check that you are not missing the [fault contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFault))]
    void DoWork();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a little experience with WCF, but I think that you're just creating a message and you're not sending it through a request or a response.
I think for this reason your client doesn't get the message with the exception.

Did you implement the method `HandleError` of the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface?

Your question is similar to these questions already asked in SO:

- [WCF IErrorHandler Extension not returning specified Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703052/wcf-ierrorhandler-extension-not-returning-specified-fault)
- [How to produce an HTTP 403-equivalent WCF Message from an IErrorHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139847/how-to-produce-an-http-403-equivalent-wcf-message-from-an-ierrorhandler)

Maybe they can help you.

Read also [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/it-IT/c37be54e-db91-42c8-8432-a4123b8c8929/how-to-use-ierrorhandle-to-return-c-data-contract?forum=wcf) in MSDN.